# Terraform error "duplicate provider configuration"

Tags: terraform-provider-aws

I have split  the variables into separate files.
I don't see any duplicate resources among these 4 files

[Terraform files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eBLlQ.gif)

Answer (score 0):

You have specified only one resource in instance.tf file.